# Next.js, how to eagerly fetch page (traditional pages router)

Tags: javascript, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have a Next.js app using next `13.4.13`. I am using the traditional pages directory.

The app has 2 pages. The directory looks like this:

`/pages/light`

`/pages/heavy`

The light page is very small, it just has a basic form on it.

The heavy page is very heavy, 10mb of babylonjs.

After login, the user is taken to pages/light , that is almost instant because the JS from `light` is so small. But now when i click on the navbar to go to the `heavy` page, there is a 2 or 3 second lag while the browser receives the huge JS file.

How can i change the settings in Next.js so that the JS from the `heavy` page gets downloaded as soon as I login / land on the light page, so that user does not have to wait after navigating to the heavy page?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, you can prefetch using Link or router.prefetch():
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#1-prefetching